# Should updating rails and active record change the behavior of .days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, rubygems

I updated rails from 5.2 to 5.2.8:

```
gem 'railties', '~> 5.2.8.1 '
gem 'actionpack', '~> 5.2.8.1 '
gem 'actionmailer', '~> 5.2.8.1 '
gem 'activejob', '~> 5.2.8.1 '
gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.2.8.1 '
gem 'activesupport', '~> 5.2.8.1 '
```

I analyzed the changes in this version and there were more additions to active record settings that shouldn't influence the app's behavior because I didn't add these new settings

But a test broke because 0.days before the update returned 0 seconds
and with the update it returns 0 days, I analyzed the gemfile.lock to check if any dependency was installed underneath, but the only one that could change the behavior is the gem data 3.3.4, but I checked the changes in this gem and they are related to the documentation

It only broke one test, but I'm afraid this behavior will affect the entire application

What could it be and how can I resolve it?

Comment: `0.days` resulting in "0 seconds" was considered a bug. It was fixed in https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37882

Comment: Trying to imagine the test where `0.days` doesn't satisfy an expectation for `0.seconds` 